# Can't let a script run at regular intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to modify the following script in such a way so that it will run at regular intervals. I know how to do the same using requests. However, in case of selenium I got stuck.

I've tried with

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_content(link):
    driver.get(link)
    for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".question-summary"))):
        title = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".question-hyperlink").text
        link = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".question-hyperlink").get_attribute("href")
        print(title,link)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    while True:
        get_content(link)
        time.sleep(20)
```

> How can I make the script run at regular intervals?

If I run as is, I get the following error in it's second attempt:

```
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51356): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/41bae2407c029ad2879619c3e65552da/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02504850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: Based on the error the server you're targeting is refusing the connection.

Comment: The same error the script encounters no matter whatever site I choose, so I suppose there is something wrong the way I created the script.

Comment: I think you shouldn't call driver.quit() in your function. You don't actually want to quit the driver until after the while True loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fn: get_content; uses driver.quit.

So, in the end it closes the driver. This means, in the next run, you need a new web driver instance.

```
def get_content(link, driver):
    driver.get(link)
    ... .. .
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        get_content(link, driver)
        time.sleep(20)
```